# Ensuring a salesman gets his commission without revealing total sales

Tags: encryption

I (ACME Corp) run a SaaS website that charges a USD amount (lets say $1) per file processed.

I directly employed a sales rep. (Alice) at 8% commission i.e. she makes 8% of $1 for every file uploaded by customers and processed.

Alice in turn sub-employed a sales rep. (Bob) at 3% commission (making Alice's actual profit from ACME 5%) who is now asking what Alice's % is so that he knows if he's really receiving 3% of the commission of the files processed. Bob is worried that Alice under-reports the number of files processed and he is getting short-changed.

Is there a way to prove to Bob that he is getting his correct commission without revealing

1. The total number of files (and thus $ value) processed by ACME Corp, and
2. Not revealing Alice's commission percentage of 8% from ACME?

Comment: Bob received \$3 and wants proof Alice made $100?

Comment: If ACME made 100 dollars then Alice would receive 5 dollars and Bob would receive 3 dollars. Bob wants proof that his commission is actually 3% without knowing ACME or Alice's income.

Comment: Potential idea: Run a secure three-party computation between Alice, Bob and ACME with everyone inputting their income and the circuit computing whether Alice's input times 10 is ACME's input and whether ACME's input times 0.03 is Bob's input?